# How to get the name and value of ContstantExpression in x => x.property

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression, constant-expression

I'm creating a simple way to get the `Name` and `Value` of Expressions in C#. However, I found a case I cannot figure out. See the code below:

```
public void GetValue_Object_TIn_Property_Test()
{
    string val = "value";
    var tuple = Tuple.Create(new object(), val);
    Expression<Func<object, string>> expression = x => tuple.Item2;

    Assert.AreEqual(val, expression.GetValue());
}
```

The `.GetValue()` method is my extension method.

Basically this expression-tree consists of a `LambdaExpression`, two `MemberExpression`s and a `ConstantExpression`, in that order.

When I try to get the name of `tuple.Item2` I get `memberExpression.Member.Name` from the last `MemberExpression`. This gives me "tuple" instead of "Item2". *How can I get "Item2" instead?*

Also, when I try to get the value of the expression, I get the entire tuple instead of `Item2`. I'm using the following method to get the value:

```
public override bool TryGetValue(
    MemberExpression memberExpression,
    out T value
) {
    value = default(T);
    bool success = false;

    var fieldInfo = memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
    if (success = (fieldInfo != null))
    {
        var valueObj = fieldInfo.GetValue(expression.Value);
        if (success = (valueObj is T || valueObj == null))
        {
            value = (T)valueObj;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Where the `MemberExpression` again is the last `MemberExpression`. *What am I doing wrong here?* *What is the exact case I am missing?*

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see why you think a `ConstantExpression` is involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the tree is a `LambdaExpression` whose `Body` is a `PropertyExpression` that has a `Member` field with a `Name` of "Item2" and an `Expression` that is a`FieldExpression` for getting the value of `tuple`. Note that `PropertyExpression` and `FieldExpression` are internal types that inherit from `MemberExpression`.

So you need to get the `(Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name` instead of the `Body.Expression.Member.Name`.

Think of the tree as `MemberExpression`(get `Member`:Item2 from `Expression`:`MemberExpression`(get `Member`:tuple from `Expression`:[surrounding class])).

Have you used LINQPad? It's `Dump()` command can show you this and more.

Comment: Thank you NetMage! I thought I was missing something - I just really did not know what. I'll download LinqPad right away - It's been a while since I used it (you know; 'That one time..'.) Thanks!!